# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'datasets')and(reading 'initialize')

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, chart.js

Update: I was able to solve the error after using method provided by Mr Ivar in the comment(In config object, change ThisMonthData to data: ThisMonthData).Thank you Ivar.

I am putting JSON data into several javascript array to do combo bar chart using chart.js and AJAX. When I tried to use the data in array to do chart, these 2 errors occur: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'datasets'), Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'initialize'). However, there is no error when I use the similar way to do another chart through different JSON data. Is there anyone can give me some hints to solve these errors,please?

[This image shows the error of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyASE.png)

[This is the desired output of my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73uUj.jpg)

This is my javascript code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>This Month Data</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        color: rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
      }
      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
        background: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chartMenu">
      <p>This Month Data</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chartCard">
      <div class="chartBox">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script>

    //Ajax Block
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //exchange data with a web server
    const url ='http://localhost/tmsignage_web/faceanalysis1.json';
 
    //send a request to a server
    xmlhttp.open('POST',url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState ==4 && this.status == 200){ //is ready and connection is success
            
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var newArray = [];
        for(var i = 0;i<myObj.ThisMonthData.length;i++){
        var newObj = myObj.ThisMonthData.filter((item) => myObj.ThisMonthData[i].Date === item.Date);
        if(newObj.length>1){
            i = i+newObj.length-1;
        }
        newObj.sort(function(a, b){return a.signage_id - b.signage_id});
        newArray.push(newObj);
        }
        var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
        var year = new Date().getFullYear();
        var month = (months.indexOf(newArray[0][0].Date.split("-")[1])+1);
        var d = new Date(year, month, 0);
        var newDateArray = []
        for(var k=0;k<d.getDate();k++){
        newDateArray.push([0,0,0,0]);
        }
        for(var l =0;l<newArray.length;l++){
            var sortbyDate = newArray[l][0].Date.split("-")[2].replace(/[^0-9]/ig,"");
            var replaceArray = [0,0,0,0]
            for(var m=0;m<newArray[l].length;m++){
            if(newArray[l][m].signage_id == 1001){
                replaceArray[0] = newArray[l][m].NumberOfPerson;
            }else if(newArray[l][m].signage_id == 1002){
                replaceArray[1] = newArray[l][m].NumberOfPerson;
            }else if(newArray[l][m].signage_id == 1003){
                replaceArray[2] = newArray[l][m].NumberOfPerson;
            }else if(newArray[l][m].signage_id == 1004){
                replaceArray[3] = newArray[l][m].NumberOfPerson;
            }    
            }
            newDateArray[sortbyDate-1] = replaceArray;
        }
        console.log(newDateArray);
        var result1001 = newDateArray.map(e => e[0]);
        var result1002 = newDateArray.map(e => e[1]);
        var result1003 = newDateArray.map(e => e[2]);
        var result1004 = newDateArray.map(e => e[3]);

        var startDate = new Date("2021-11-01"); //YYYY-MM-DD
        var endDate = new Date("2021-11-30"); //YYYY-MM-DD
        var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
        var arr = new Array();
        var dt = new Date(start);
        while (dt <= end) {
            arr.push(new Date(dt));
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);   
        }
        return arr;
        }
        var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);
        dateArr = dateArr.map((element) => {
            var d = new Date(element);
            return `${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getDate()}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
        })

        console.log(dateArr);
        console.log(result1001);
        console.log(result1002);
        console.log(result1003);
        console.log(result1004);

        const ThisMonthData = {
        labels: dateArr,
        datasets: [{
            label: '1001',
            data: result1001,
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)'               
            ],
            borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }
        ,
        {
            label: '1002',
            data: result1002,
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: '1003',
            data: result1003,
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: '1004',
            data: result1004,
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }
        ]
        };
        //config 
        const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        ThisMonthData,
        options: {
            scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
            }
        }
        };
        //render init block
        const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
        );
    }
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my JSON file:

```
{"ThisMonthData":[
    {"signage_id":1001,"NumberOfPerson":4,"Date":"2021-November-1st"},
    {"signage_id":1002,"NumberOfPerson":7,"Date":"2021-November-2nd"},
    {"signage_id":1001,"NumberOfPerson":43,"Date":"2021-November-2nd"},
    {"signage_id":1002,"NumberOfPerson":1,"Date":"2021-November-3rd"},
    {"signage_id":1002,"NumberOfPerson":2,"Date":"2021-November-4th"},
    {"signage_id":1001,"NumberOfPerson":105,"Date":"2021-November-9th"},
    {"signage_id":1002,"NumberOfPerson":31,"Date":"2021-November-9th"},
    {"signage_id":1001,"NumberOfPerson":72,"Date":"2021-November-10th"},
    {"signage_id":1001,"NumberOfPerson":151,"Date":"2021-November-11th"}],
"LastMonthData":[{
    "signage_id":1000,"NumberOfPerson":7,"Date":"2021-September-2nd"},
    {"signage_id":1000,"NumberOfPerson":40,"Date":"2021-September-5th"},
    {"signage_id":1000,"NumberOfPerson":26,"Date":"2021-September-6th"},
    {"signage_id":1000,"NumberOfPerson":16,"Date":"2021-September-8th"},
    {"signage_id":1000,"NumberOfPerson":16,"Date":"2021-September-12th"},
    {"signage_id":1000,"NumberOfPerson":156,"Date":"2021-September-13th"},
    {"signage_id":1003,"NumberOfPerson":66,"Date":"2021-September-13th"},
    {"signage_id":1003,"NumberOfPerson":77,"Date":"2021-September-14th"},
    {"signage_id":1003,"NumberOfPerson":4,"Date":"2021-September-16th"},
    {"signage_id":1003,"NumberOfPerson":19,"Date":"2021-September-17th"},
    {"signage_id":1003,"NumberOfPerson":5,"Date":"2021-September-19th"},
    {"signage_id":1001,"NumberOfPerson":15,"Date":"2021-September-27th"},
    {"signage_id":1001,"NumberOfPerson":10,"Date":"2021-September-29th"}],
"success":true,"message":""}
```

Comment: Can you add the actual error to the post and point out on which line the error is thrown?

Comment: @Ivar Yes sir, I just edited my question. But I still confused how to solve those errors.

Comment: The error seems to be thrown by the library that provides the `new Chart(...)`. Can you tell which library you are using here?

Comment: @Ivar Sir,here I use Chart.js to do combo bar chart.

Comment: In your `config` object, can you try to change `ThisMonthData` to `data: ThisMonthData` and see if that makes any difference?